# varchar2 in Oracle becomes num in R

Tags: r, oracle, transformation

I have a table tbl_Rum in Oracle database and it has a column AAB varchar2(12). A value from AAB is `004410001600'`. But after I imported into R via ODBC with the following code, this AAB became a num column and the two leading zeroes disappeared. Is there a way of avoiding this column transformation?

Thanks

```
conODBC<-odbcConnect(dsn="xxxxx", uid="xxxx", pwd="xxxx", readOnly=FALSE)
tbl_Rum<-sqlQuery(conODBC, "select * from tbl_Rum", rows_at_time=1)
str(tbl_Rum)


'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:

$ AAA: Factor w/ 2 levels "H31000000000000",..: 1 1 2

$ AAB: num  4.41e+09 7.39e+09 1.89e+10
```

Comment: try `as.is=TRUE`? from doc, as.is --- which (if any) columns returned as character should be converted to another
type? Allowed values are as for read.table. See ‘Details’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, `sqlQuery(channel,"select ...",as.is=TRUE)` works!